# How do I build .war file in Eclipse for Glassfish server

Tags: java, eclipse, build-process

I have web application written in java using Eclipse. It has just one servlet that does some file manipulations. How do I build war file so I can easily deploy it to my remote server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right-click on the project, select 'Export...', then choose web -> WAR.

Comment: Awesome!!! It workssss... Actually Eclipse is better than Netbeans (in some ways) :D

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use Maven to package a WAR to deploy to your remote server.  It looks a little daunting, but once you create your own WAR file you should be ok, check out:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html

In fact you should be able to manage deployment using the Maven Glassfish plugin here:

https://maven-glassfish-plugin.dev.java.net/

That will allow you to start,stop,deploy,undeploy etc... your web app.  Example here:

https://maven-glassfish-plugin.dev.java.net/examples/complete.html

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record,

- The default build artifact for a
  NetBeans Web project is a **war**
- The default build artifact for a simple
  Java project is a **jar**

Comment: Yeah... That's why I love NetBeans but I have to learn and user Eclipse for work.